# iOS Present Full Screen view on UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, viewcontroller

Developing for an iPhone, I have a main view controller that presents a second "Share" view controller using a transition of UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl.  These seems to make sense from a UI perspective as it can just take up a little bit of space showing a few share buttons at the bottom while keeping the user on the main view.  At this point, if I have a button launch a third view (MFMailComposeViewController in this case) the mailer view will present itself underneath the curl of the previous view, making it unusable.

I would like for the third Mail view to break out and present itself entirely, is this not possible?

Feel free to shoot me down if I'm messing up Apple UI standards or something here.

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting the mail vc from the presentingViewController after dismissing the vc under the curl.  That approach would look like this:

In the FirstVC (the one that triggers the curl transition):

FirstVC.h

```
- (void)presentMail;
```

FirstVC.m

```
- (void)presentMail {
    // the code to present the mail UI, moved here from the SecondVC under the curl
}
```

SecondVC.m

```
- (IBAction)userPressedTheMailButton:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.presentingViewController presentMail];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me a

Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0xa26d390> on <ViewController: 0x95856e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

but I will say that I'm not using the navigationController in this circumstance, is that what is screwing me up?

The naming here is weird "to present" (command) and "the preSent" are kind of confusing.  I'm guessing "presentingViewController refers to what presented 'self' and presentViewController is the command to present?

Comment: Hmm.  Sorry it didn't work.  It's a weird error, though.  You're right that presentingViewController refers to the view controller that presented the current one (across the sdk, present is a verb meaning to make visible to the user).  Why wouldn't the presenting VC's view be in the hierarchy?  Can you move the mail code into that first vc temporarily, and see if it works there?

Comment: Hopefully it does.  The idea behind my answer was to get that first VC to do the mail presentation.  presentingViewController was just a short cut.  If it works on the first vc, then you just need a way to convey that from the vc under the curl.  When it gets the button press, dismiss itself and alert the top one.

Comment: One other point - the UI that I think you're trying to achieve is often done using a UIActionSheet.

Comment: Some interesting points.  Can I do this with the UIActionSheet? I think I could pull it off with the activity view controller, but it's not quite the aesthetic I was looking for. I'm not sure that I can actually put this on the presenting controller without dismissing the present controller -- which may not be bad.  I will fool around a bit more with that.